RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') in Django Rest Framework with Google Generative AI
I am using Google Generative AI using Django Rest Framework. I send a request in my backend with adrf (async views package), I can process my answer with Gemini pro, but when I send other request I get this error:
raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
[11/Apr/2024 15:20:49] "POST /api/chatbot/ HTTP/1.1" 500 165320
C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\chatbot-django-entrevista\apps\chatbot\views\gemini_views.py changed, reloading.
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UnaryUnaryCall._invoke' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

This is my code:
import google.generativeai as genai
genai.configure(api_key=settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY)

@async_api_view(['POST'])
async def post_message(request):
    """
    This view post a message
    """

    model = genai.GenerativeModel(settings.MODEL)
    messages = [
        {'role':'user',
        'parts': ["Briefly explain how a computer works to a young child."]}
        ]
    response = await model.generate_content_async(messages)
    print(response)

    return Response({'msg':'text'})

